# Regex to match and group up to first period and last slash

Tags: regex

I am working on creating a regular expression that matches and groups in the following way:

Example input:
`hello.world1/world2/index.js`

Example desired regex grouping:
`[hello].[world1/world2]/[index.js]`

Where anything NOT inside the brackets is ignored. I currently have this Regex: `(^.*\.)(.*\/)(.*$)` and is capturing the following:

[image: current regex]

Notice how group 1 includes the period and group 2 includes the last slash. Both which I don't want. Any help to correct this regex would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `^([^.]*)\.(.*)\/(.*)$` then, see https://regex101.com/r/VJeYhO/1. Basically, move the chars out of the groups.

Comment: What about having only `index.js`? it's not a string worth matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the literal chars out of the capturing groups:

```py
^([^.]*)\.(.*)\/(.*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VJeYhO/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5B%5E.%5D*)%5C.(.*)%5C%2F(.*)%24):

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `([^.]*)` - any zero or more chars other than a `.` char as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - string end.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks :D